# Javascript appear/disappear objects

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project right now. When you click on one item the info below appears, i wanted to know how to make it disappear when you click on the next item without reclicking the same item....For example I have pizza's in my project, I want to click meat pizza to see the toppings then click on cheese pizza to see the toppings and the meat toppings disappear.

Here is my Html code....

```
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td><fieldset style="border:1px solid red;padding:5px; 
margin-bottom:10px;width:200px; height:150px">
<a onclick ="javascript:ShowHide('HiddenDiv')" href="#Meat">Meat Pizza</a>

</fieldset></td>

<td><fieldset style="border:1px solid red;padding:5px; 
margin-bottom:10px; width:200px; height:150px">
<a onclick ="javascript:ShowHide('HiddenDiv2')" href="#Cheese">
Cheese Pizza</a>

</fieldset></td>

<td><fieldset style="border:1px solid red;padding:5px; 
margin-bottom:10px; width:200px; height:150px;">
<a onclick ="javascript:ShowHide('HiddenDiv3')" href="#Veggie">
Veggie Pizza</a>

</fieldset></td>
</tr>
</table>

<div class="mid" id="HiddenDiv" style="DISPLAY: none" align="center">
<a name="Meat">
<table>
<tr><td width="220">Meat Toppings</td></tr>

</table>

</a>
</div>

<div class="mid" id="HiddenDiv2" style="DISPLAY: none" align="center">
<a name="Cheese">
<table>
<tr><td width="220">Cheese Toppings</td></tr>

</table>
</a>
</div>

<div class="mid" id="HiddenDiv3" style="DISPLAY: none" align="center">
<a name="Veggie">
<table>
<tr><td width="220">Veggie Toppings</td></tr>
</table>
</a>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript......

```
function ShowHide(divId)
{
if(document.getElementById(divId).style.display == 'none')
{
document.getElementById(divId).style.display='block';
}
else
{
document.getElementById(divId).style.display = 'none';
}
}


function showApp(a) {
var aside = document.getElementById('aside');
var arr = aside.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].getAttribute('id') != a) {
        arr[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
x = document.getElementById(a);
var state;
if (x.style.visibility == 'visible') {
    state = 'hidden';
}
else {
    state = 'visible';
}
x.style.visibility = state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `for` loop in `ShowHide()` function like this :

**UPDATED**

```
ShowHide = function(divId)
{
    if(document.getElementById(divId).style.display == 'none')
    {
        var alltexts = document.getElementsByClassName('mid');
        for(var i=0;i<alltexts.length;i++)
            alltexts[i].style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(divId).style.display='block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(divId).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

In ShowHide we have to hide all texts before showing the clicked item text .

Find Working Fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/0p4Lj5nc/1/).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for but could not think of. Thank you so much, It works perfectly!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions for example:

1. You may create global JS element which will contain current showed element and update it every click.
2. You may on every click hide all elements at first and then show required element.